# Is there any good reason not to rely on DB key integrity in business logic?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, business-logic

I'm writing a method that will allow inserts into a link table in my DB, and I'm wondering whether I need to first check to make sure the PKs specified actually exist in the linked tables.  It seems logical to me that I can just rely 100% on the database to enforce these FK constraints for me, as well as preventing duplicate table entries via the table's PK.  In fact, it seems quite redundant and a waste of resources for me to check these beforehand if the DB is just going to check them anyway.  Also, note that I'm talking about very basic RDBMS concepts here; I'd expect them to be equally enforced even if switching to another data store mechanism.

So under these circumstances, is there any good reason not to rely on the database entirely to ensure data integrity for the FK and PK?  In other words:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {
    try {
        context.LinkEntries.Add(new LinkEntry { key1 = x, key2 = y });
        return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException) {
        // Duplicate, or foreign key violation
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I rely on database constraints, that's what they're for.

Comment: I agree. Database constraints are the way to go. You do need to handle the error message that the database comes back with on the front end though.

Comment: @MichaelHarmon Yeah, that's kind of the problem.  Entity Framework doesn't really make any attempt at providing a generic way to determine what kind of SQL error you have; different connectors have custom Exceptions, so the SQL Server one has `SqlException` and a popular Postgres one has `NpgsqlException`.  It would've been cool if Microsoft had defined `SqlException` as a generic cross-DBMS class that had to specify things like an enum entry giving you error type `PrimaryKeyViolation` or whatever.

Comment: Could you create this class?

Comment: It wouldn't be any good because different connectors create their own SQL exception classes with different formats; how would this new class even be populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relational databases will enforce referential integrity - assuming you've set up the foreign keys correctly.

1) This will ensure `key1` and `key2` actually point to rows in the primary tables.

2) If you also want to ensure only one row with a particular pair of foreign keys can exist in the link table, you will have to add a unique constraint in the database on those columns.

If you are using the pair of foreign keys as your link table primary key, you should be fine.